# Redirecting After a Form Submission

Tags: javascript, php, forms, redirect, registration

How can I make this form redirect the user to an external site, for example http://amaze.bg, after the user submits the form with the "Register" button and after the form sends the e-mail to antoniya.p@amaze.bg with the entered by the user details?

Here is the PHP code (contact_process.php):

```
<?php

usleep(500000);
$to = "antoniya.p@amaze.bg";
$author = "";
$email = "";
$comment = "";
$class = "FORM CONTACT ";

if (isset($_POST['input_name']))
    $author = $_POST['input_name'];
if (isset($_POST['input_email']))
    $email = $_POST['input_email'];
if (isset($_POST['input_class']))
    $class = $_POST['input_class'];
if (isset($_POST['input_message']))
    $comment = $_POST['input_message'];

$sub="Alumni registration recieved - ".$date1;
       $name=$authorlast."< ".$email." >";

    $msg = '';
    if (@mail($to,$sub,$body,"Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"))
        {
            $msg = 'Your registration was sent successfully';
            //echo '<div class="alert success pngfix">'. $msg .'</div>';
        }
        else{
            $msg = 'Email failed to be sent (mail function not work)';
            //echo '<div class="alert error pngfix">'. $msg .'</div>';
        }

    echo $msg;


?>
```

And here is the .js part:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
        "math", 
        function(value, element, params) { 
            if (value==='')
                return false;
            return this.optional(element) || value == params[0] + params[1]; 
        },
        jQuery.format("Please enter the correct value for {0} + {1}")
    );
    $('.form-register').validate({
        rules: {
            input_name: {
                minlength: 3,
                required: true
            },
            input_email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            input_message: {
                minlength: 0,
                required: false
            }
            ,
            submitHandler: function(form) {
            var a=$('.form-register').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "contact_process.php",
                data:a,
                complete:function(){
                },
                beforeSend: function() {

                },
                success: function(data){
                    if (data=='success') {
                        $('.form-register').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
                        alert('You have successfully registered. Thank you for being active alumni!');
                    } else {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                },
                error : function() {

                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });


});
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In Your Success Callback, Add location = "http://amaze.bg"

```
success: function(data) {
    // if you echo "success" in your php script when the mail is sent 
    if (data === 'success') {
        $('.form-register').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
        alert('You have successfully registered. Thank you for being active alumni!');
        // Now redirect
        location = "http://amaze.bg"
    } else {
        // if you echo "Some Error Message" from your php script
        alert(data);
    }
},
```

Ultimately, You should be sending the proper headers from php so that the success hook in your $.ajax fires on a 200 Status Code and the error hook fires in your $.ajax when a 400 - 500 Status Code is encountered. Please look into [HTTP Status Codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) and [Sending Proper Headers in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php)

Comment: I added the location to the Success Callback, but nothing changed. Once the user submits the form, it sends the information to the server, shows the alert message "Your registration was sent successfully", but does not redirect the user to the external URL. How should I change the code so that the form redirects the user to http://example.com, after all entered information has been submited using the button?

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments and help from Charlie I managed to find where and what exactly to add to the code, so that the form sends the information to the server and them redirects the user to another website. The change should be made in the .js file with the addition of the following line:

```
location = "http://amaze.bg/"
```

But it should be added under "else" in the .js file, with the "alert" being under "success" for everything to work properly:

```
success: function(data){
            if (data=='success') {

            alert(data);

            } else {

            location = "http://amaze.bg/"

            }
        },
            error : function() {

            }
```